# Permanent_Dialog_Message

Tags: android

i want to show dialog box as message got displayed user must not allowed to go anywhere.just that message must shown....please give me some code with XML too......

Comment: Wat is the motivation behind this. You mean to say the dialog box should stay permanently on the screen??

Comment: yup dialog box must stay on screen.....till i didnt close it...

Comment: please give me some simple code

Answer (score 1):

[Creating Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Refer the above link for how to create the dialogs in Android